# matching values with elements using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and its look like this

```
[
 ["fish","animal","tree"],
 "science"
]
```

if this same array is like i can solve it

```js
let arr= ["Science",["fish","animal","tree"]];
let out= arr[1].map((rest)=>[arr[0],rest]);
console.log(out);
```

I tried to this but got no success

```js
let arr= [["fish","animal","tree"],"science"];
let out= arr[0].map((rest)=>[arr[1],rest]);
console.log(out);
```

I am trying to get output of my array like this

```
["fish","science"],
["animal","science"],
["tree","science"]
```

not like this

```
[["fish","science"],
 ["animal","science"],
 ["tree","science"]]
```

Comment: Are you sure? it works for me. Or to get "science" *after* the first element, you want to have let out= arr[0].map((rest)=>[rest,arr[1]]);

Comment: Hey @Felix i just updated my question can i get output like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to flip the `rest` and `arr[1]` values in the array when you `map`.

```js
let arr= [["fish","animal","tree"],"science"];
let out= arr[0].map((rest)=>[rest, arr[1]]);
console.log(out);
```

Comment: hey Sorry @Nick for trouble i made some changes in my question can i get output like this ? if possible please help

Comment: The format you’re looking for is not legitimate javascript syntax. It has to be an array of arrays.

Comment: @Vikas Do you want to print or wanna store it in some form of data structure. If you only want to print on the console then it would be fine, it can be achievable but you can't just store the form that you want. First of all it's not possible and second what's the use of it?

Comment: can you help me to remove those extra [] as i put `out.join(",");` but its giving me unexpected output its removing all the bracket